# netcode free unity assets makes second screen xbox controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, local, multiplayer

iam learing with netcode but i have a problem with the testing. when the second player joins the host. i cant move the second player. but when i look at the player input system debug. the first player(HOST) gets the keyboard and mouse and the second screen(Client) gets xbox but there is no xbox controller connected[image]

[image]

why is this happening. i dont know how to fix it.
in the code i already have if(!isOwmer) return.
and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I think its down to the keyboard already being assigned. To get past it I added this code to the update method after the `IsOwner`

```
if (!IsOwner) return;

_playerInput.SwitchCurrentControlScheme(Keyboard.current, Mouse.current);
```

Comment: I made my own input chart without the Xbox controller

Comment: Worked fine to just put it at the end of the Start method. But thank you!